# iOS: is it possible to attechment of MFMailComposeViewController with Animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am working on attach images into `MFMailComposeViewController` everything is fine working but i want to know that is it Possible to give animation of Attachment?

**For Ex:-**  When we attach images from Photo Gallery in iPhone Device. and while select mail Button that all selected Images Move's in `MailComposeViewcontroller` with Nice **ANIMATION**.

So please can any-buddy guide me this stuff is possible or not.? and if YES then how can i set Animation of Attachment.

Comment: No this not possibly by default.That functionality does'n provided by iphone in xcode.

Comment: Thank's your Reply how can you say that..? u have any doc link that mansion this is not possible please i want to bcz i need to show my boss so.

Comment: Sorry but i have no any doc for this .sorry bro.i am not able for this help you .sorry

Comment: See my answer. Its not possible to do the exact same thing as the Apple's mail does, but you can at least simulate similar effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is iOS custom animation effects and is not exposed as iOS API's so no you cannot get this effect out of box. The reason I know that this effect is not exposed to developers is from [Apple iOS 6 Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a). There is only one method which deals with `animate` and its the standard one.

What you can try is this. After the user has selected image(s) from his photo gallery (i.e. from `ALAssetsLibrary`) you can animate a "image" that looks like a `MFMailComposeViewController`. The animation would similar to what iOS provides i.e. background fading, `MFMailComposeViewController` appearing and the images sitting in the "body" section of the mail. Once the animation finishes, remove the "image" of `MFMailComposeViewController` and show the actual call `MFMailComposeViewController` invoked with `animaiton:FALSE` option. Hope I was clear. Essentially what you are providing is an illusion of `MFMailComposeViewController` and once animation is done, taking away the illusion and showing the reality.

Theoretically this could work but exact animation timing and user perceived feel has to be tested out.

Comment: nice explanation. might be that could be hard to implement..?

Comment: @NitinGohel implementation is not that hard.But you might have to play around with the animation timings to get the effect right, so that the user does not feel the shift. And please dont call me sir! thats what people call my grandpa !!

Comment: one last advise. Study the ios animation carefully. look closely as to what elements are moving/changing/fading/disappearing/timing etc. note it down and try to replicate it in your code. it should be fun!

Comment: yes i m trying and surely try to do this in fatch and display images from Photo gallery to viewcontroller, thx for advice.

Answer (score 2):

There exists some semi-solution. You can in fact add any `UIView` as subview of you main app's window. It will than sit on top of all apps content. Using this you can *simulate* animation of attaching image to `MailComposeViewcontroller`

See my example code. This code slides image view from top of the screen to mail composer so it imitates adding of image as attachment. Everything is commented.

```
//  Get apps main window
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

//  Setup frames of animated image view in apps window - adjust to your needs
CGRect finalImageFrame = CGRectMake(30, 220, window.frame.size.width-60, 100);
CGRect initialImageFrame = finalImageFrame;
initialImageFrame.origin.y = -initialImageFrame.size.height;

//  Create image view to be animated as attachment
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
imageView.frame = initialImageFrame;
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

//  Add animated image view to window
[window addSubview:imageView];

//  Animate image view with slide in from top
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                 animations:^{
                     imageView.frame = finalImageFrame;
                 }];

//  Present mail composer
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:^{

    //  Once the controller appears, hide the image view - adjust this animation according to you needs
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^{
                         imageView.alpha = 0;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [imageView removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

}];
```

Of course the code may need some adjustments and polishing, but it shows the concept. You can play with animations to make some better effect. There is a lot of animation tweaks I would add, but I wanted to keep the example code as short at it can be ;-)